# Ideal Colors for Saving, Editing, Logging Out and Deleting Confirmation Boxes

Tags: interface-design, color

I have a question on what's the ideal colors for the ff:

1. Creating Form
2. Saving Confirmation Dialog
3. Editing Form
4. Editing Confirmation Dialog
5. Log out
6. Delete Confirmation Dialog

The colors i have for my app is this

1. Primary - blue
2. Secondary - light grey
3. Success - green
4. Warning - orange
5. Error  - red

I need it to be put on the header part and the button also. Something like this in the picture below

[image: PIC]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Answers to this question will be opinion based. Unfortunately that means it's not really answerable by facts.  There are no set rules for this kind of thing. There are no right or wrong answers. Do what you want.

Comment: "Ideal" for who? Men? Women? 10-18 year olds? 18-35? 35-50? 50+? Affluent? Middle -class? Lower-class? Educated? High School graduates? Hunters? Mothers? Fathers? Welders? Programmers? Non-drinkers? Vegans? Singles? Couples? Smokers? Non-Smokers? Christians? Buddhists? Muslims? Atheists? Republicans? Democrats? Students? Teachers? ..... This list could be infinite. Without knowing the **audience** even a "best guess" could *never* be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the colors?

**Orientation**

You want to use color to help people understand the structure of your app (Home, News, Settings, User). Use a calm, not an alerting color (blue, grey).

**Alerting**

If it is about giving people a warning once they initiate an action (e.g. "You are about to log out of application X. Unsaved progress will be lost. Are you sure?"), I would go with a more alerting color such as orange or red.

All of this can also be done with text or icons. Color is not necessarily needed. Vital information should also be accessible for people with color blindness.

**Options**

Option 1: Color everything according to the area

- 1,2: blue
- 3,4: orange
- 5: grey
- 6: red

Option 2: Pages are one color, confirmation dialogs another color

- 1,3,5: blue
- 2,4,6: orange

Comment: Thanks! Let's say i have a create user form. The form should be what color? Blue? And what about the confirmation box that would say "save user?" Is it green? I have edited my question by the way. Thanks